# Logic problem: How to get cell image to keep flipping even after user has panned over once?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer, caanimation

**Goal:** Have it so that when a user pans over the collection view, the image within that current cell flips once. If the user pans over that image again (even within the same continuous touch), the image flips once again.

[What it should be doing](https://giphy.com/gifs/Alt9Nw7Jdg2PYVlyDY)

**Problem:** After the user has panned over an image once, the image will no longer flip, regardless of whether it's the same touch or a new one. I know this is a logic problem. Just not sure how to properly manipulate the control flow here... Very much appreciate anyone taking a crack at this!

[What it's doing](https://giphy.com/gifs/6dbyjUhmAHnjV7lsGp)

```
class GameTileCVC: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .black
    self.collectionView!.register(GameTileCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: GameTileCell.reuseID)
    addPan()
}


func addPan() {
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(sender:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}


@objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView)) {
        let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! GameTileCell
        let location = sender.location(in: collectionView)
        
        switch sender.state {
        case .began, .changed, .ended:
            if cell.frame.contains(location) && !cell.hasBeenFlipped {
                flip(sender: sender, cell: cell)    // hasBeenFlipped = true
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


func flip(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer, view: GameTileCell) {
    let direction = sender.direction(in: collectionView)
    if direction.contains(.Right) {
        UIView.transition(with: view.gameTileImageView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft) {
            self.setImageAndColor(for: view)
        }
    } else if direction.contains(.Left) {
        UIView.transition(with: view.gameTileImageView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight) {
            self.setImageAndColor(for: view)
        }
    } else if direction.contains(.Up) {
        UIView.transition(with: view.gameTileImageView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromTop) {
            self.setImageAndColor(for: view)
        }
    } else {
        UIView.transition(with: view.gameTileImageView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromBottom) {
            self.setImageAndColor(for: view)
        }
    }
cell.hasBeenFlipped = true
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that you are not checking the state of the gesture recognizer. You are not tracking the gesture at all. You are just screaming flip over and over.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the honest feedback. Wasn't sure if I needed to track state since I think I need it to do the same thing regardless of its state, but I think you're right in that it's best practice. I've now edited the OP and included it along with functioning links

Comment: Is a pan gesture recognizer even right? For a single swipe you need a swipe gesture recognizer.

Comment: @matt My reasoning for using pan is because I believe (and I could be wrong) swipe will only track one direction per touch. In my case, I need to track multiple directions in one touch... Perhaps a custom gesture recognizer is in order here?

Comment: If you merely want to detect all four directions then use four swipe gesture recognizers.

Comment: @matt In this case I also need to track the movement of the finger because one touch should be able to contain multiple directions. A swipe requires the user’s finger to move in a specific direction and not deviate significantly from that main direction.